# Disabling nonce check in Apache mod_cluster

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, mod-cluster

I am trying to write a shell script on my Apache server with mod_cluster to enable and disable contexts. However, it is not working because of the nonce. How do I disable the check for this?

Googling shows that there is a CheckNonce option but does not indicate into which configuration file it should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckNonce` is part of [mod_manager](https://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/native.config.html#d0e624) config, you can set `CheckNonce Off` in your Apache `mod_cluster` config.

Eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:6666>

    <Location />
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 10.33.144.
    </Location>

    CheckNonce Off

    ....

</VirtualHost>
```